# Логично ли максимально минимизировать количество кода js за счет css?

Tags: javascript, css, оптимизация

Лучше ли реализовывать функцию с помощью количества кода CSS *n * 10* вместо *n* количества кода на js? Что предпочтительнее со стороны нагрузки на браузер, качества кода, уровня верстальщика?

Comment: Тут смотреть нужно на ситуацию в которой вы хотите это применять

Comment: Думаю сильно от бизнес трбований к приложению зависеть будет. Попробуйте, потестируйте (benchmark), поделитесь результатом :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, что делается при помощи css, при условии, что css для этого непосредственно предназначен (ну например, это НЕ реализация табов на css) следует делать на css.

Если уж совсем никак, то на js. Но скорее всего там выплывут проблемы с динамическим формированием контента, ресайзом окна и другими штуками, когда css браузер пересчитывает сам, а js вообще и не в курсе, что надо бы пересчитаться.

А вот невизуальное взаимодействие с пользователем на css вместо js делать не надо. Всякие клики по кнопкам, табам и другие реакции на события в большинстве случаев должны быть на js.